# laravel google map current position

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

My javascript Code here is giving me lat and lang if only I moved the curser I need when I get location 
lat and lang will get updated to and if I didn't  move the cursor or choose location default not working

Here I get current location

```
 const getCurrentPosition = function () {
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        return;
    }

    const geoLocation = navigator.geolocation;

    const currentPositionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        geoLocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
                resolve(position.coords);
            },
            error => reject(error)
        );
    });

    return currentPositionPromise;
};

getCurrentPosition()
    .then(pos => console.log(pos.latitude, pos.longitude))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This is My Main Function first I get current location

```
function initialize() {
    getCurrentPosition()
    .then(pos => {
        var e = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude),
        t = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: e,
            panControl: !0,
            scrollwheel: 1,
            scaleControl: !0,
            overviewMapControl: !0,
            overviewMapControlOptions: {
                opened: !0
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.terrain
        };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("latlongmap"), t), geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder, marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: e,
        map: map
    }), map.streetViewControl = !1, infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "("+pos.latitude+","+ pos.longitude+"))"
    }), google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
        marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        var t = e.latLng,
            o = "(" + t.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + t.lng().toFixed(6) + ")";
        infowindow.setContent(o),
            document.getElementById("lat").value = t.lat().toFixed(6),
            document.getElementById("lng").value = t.lng().toFixed(6)
    })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        var e = new google.maps.LatLng(24.701925,46.675415),
        t = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: e,
            panControl: !0,
            scrollwheel: 1,
            scaleControl: !0,
            overviewMapControl: !0,
            overviewMapControlOptions: {
                opened: !0
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.terrain
        };
```

I think the problem is here  in this code below

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("latlongmap"), t), geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder, marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: e,
        map: map
    }), map.streetViewControl = !1, infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "(24.701925,46.675415))"
    }), google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
        marker.setPosition(e.latLng);
        var t = e.latLng,
            o = "(" + t.lat().toFixed(6) + ", " + t.lng().toFixed(6) + ")";
        infowindow.setContent(o),
            document.getElementById("lat").value = t.lat().toFixed(6),
            document.getElementById("lng").value = t.lng().toFixed(6)
    })
    });

}
```

Comment: Use Geolocation API. To obtain your current location, you can call the getCurrentPosition() method. This initiates an asynchronous request to detect the user's position, and queries the positioning hardware to get up-to-date information.

When the position is determined, the defined callback function is executed. You can optionally provide a second callback function to be executed if an error occurs. A third, optional, parameter is an options object where you can set the maximum age of the position returned, the time to wait for a request, and if you want high accuracy for the position.